# Best practice to share domain model between two microservices

Tags: microservices

Are there any best practices or guidelines on how to share the domain model between two micro-services?

I have a micro-service (1) which provides end points to interact with a resource (e.g, Order) all CRUD and the other micro-service (2) which performs a specific non CRUD task on the resource (Order). The micro-service (2) almost needs all the order attributes to perform its operation. In this case, does it make sense to create a common shared lib of the domain model and share between the two services? I could technically combine 1 and 2 together but the micro-service (2) needs to support scalability as it is quite memory and CPU intensive.

Comment: You need something like domain model layer

Comment: @MegaTron Could you elaborate a little on what you mean by domain model layer?

Comment: Creating a common shared library can have serious repercussions. You should consider creating a separate service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it seems that these two services need to share the same data and you are thinking to share also the library that is used to read/modify this data.

They seem to belong to the same "bounded context" and so it would be ideal to consider them as a unique service.

If you really can't separate  their data and their logic, it would be better to keep them together.

I do not think that components in the same microservices have to follow the same deployment pattern: they will be the same microservice, managed by the same team, deployed always together, sharing the same source repository, but they will be deployed with a different strategy because only the second component needs high scalability.

So same bounded context, same service, but different components.

I do not have a lot of experience and so take this as my personal thought.

Comment: The shared library is just a bunch of simple POJOs primarily used to share the data structure for serializing/deserializing between the services. Sounds like what I am considering is not an anti-pattern.