# Reusable code for two different microservices (API's)

Tags: architecture, microservices

We have microservices architecture project with two API:

- External user API - API for users who are registered/logged in our website.
- Internal user API - API for users who are not registered in our website and who makes request from another website (users don't know about our website X, they just making request to  site Y and site Y makes request to our site to get data for user).

Format of requests/responses are totally different for both APIs, but processing/logic - totally same.

Question - how to keep two different services (API) but not copy-paste code for processing?

Technologies we use: Python(Flask).

Comment: is it out of question to have the external API call the internal API behind the scenes? (after doing some request argument formatting)

Comment: yes, I was thinking about it as well, sounds OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a microservices architecture, you want to keep your services as independent of each other as possible. Therefore, a typical advice is to [avoid sharing](https://phauer.com/2016/dont-share-libraries-among-microservices/) or [reusing](https://blog.bitsrc.io/the-dilemma-of-code-reuse-in-microservices-a925ff2b9981) business logic between the services.

So I see the following options:

- Use only one service with both the internal and the external
  interfaces.
- Create a new service for the common logic.

Further reading:

- [Best practice to share domain model between two microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860278/best-practice-to-share-domain-model-between-two-microservices)
- [Why shared libraries between microservices are bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48961000/why-shared-libraries-between-microservices-are-bad)