# Architecturing a django microservice project

Tags: django, microservices

I am trying to build a project using micro-service architecture. I have several Typescript services and I want to integrate the services from a Django project to my services.

My Django project expose multiple URLs and some commands, and I would like to have a distinct service for each of these.

Here is the file structure I expect for my services :

```
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── service-1
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── Dockerfile 
│   │   │   ├── // Typescript service 
│   │   ├── infrastructure
│   │   │   ├── // Terraform resources
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   └── README.md
│   ├── service-2
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── // Typescript service 
│   │   ├── infrastructure
│   │   │   ├── // Terraform resources
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   └── README.md
│   ├── django-service-1
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── // TODO : What would be the structure of my django service here ?  
│   │   ├── infrastructure
│   │   │   ├── // Terraform resources
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   └── README.md
│   ├── django-service-2
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── // TODO : What would be the structure of my django service here ?  
│   │   ├── infrastructure
│   │   │   ├── // Terraform resources
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── project.json
│   │   └── README.md
```

My issue is that there is some shared code between my Django services and I want to avoid duplicating code. What would be the proper Django way to do that ?

Comment: Few questions I have:
1. Why are you bundling those services in one package?Why can't those services be separated and maintained separately if it's an microservice architecture?
2. What kind of shared code do you have between your Django services? Is that authentication or logging or some business logic?

Comment: 1 : I have a mono-repo with a shared CI/CD so that's why all of my services are at the same place.
2 : I have a bit of everything, some connectors for example, and some algorithms that can be used by multiple services

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578081/reusable-code-for-two-different-microservices-apis)? (talks about sharing code between microservices in general, not specifically about Django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tips for shared code:

**Shared Library:**

- Consider creating a shared library (like a Python package) that
  includes common code used across different Django services. This
  might include custom Django middleware, utility functions, base
  classes, or shared models.
- Structure this library similar to any Python package with its
  setup.py and organize code into modules.
- Include this package in the requirements.txt of each service that
  needs it.

**Django Apps as Shared Modules:**

- If the shared code is Django-specific (like shared models, admin
  interfaces, or view utilities), you might structure them as reusable
  Django apps. Each app can be included in the INSTALLED_APPS of each
  Django project that requires it.

And according to microservices:

- Each service (including each Django service) should have its own
  Dockerfile for containerization, ensuring isolated environments and
  dependencies.
- In a microservices architecture, you might need a way for services to
  discover and communicate with each other, tools like Kubernetes

For each Django service (django-service-1, django-service-2, ...), the structure within the app directory might look something like this:

```
django-service-n
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── Dockerfile 
│   │   ├── manage.py
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   ├── service_name/  # Django app specific to this service
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   │   ├── models.py
│   │   │   ├── views.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   └── tests/
│   │   ├── project_name/  # Django project settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   │   └── wsgi.py
│   │   └── static/  # Static files like CSS, JavaScript, etc.
```